# Temperature of a muffin pan right under a gas oven broiler

Tags: baking, oven

I have a gas oven stove that can go up to 550°F (~287°C), with also a gas broiler. If I place a muffin pan on the top or second top rack, under the broiler, after preheating the oven at its highest setting, what sort of temperatures might the muffin pan reach?

The end goal's to make some Portuguese egg tarts and I hear that generally it should be cooked as high as the oven can go, so I'm wondering what temperatures the muffin pan needs to tolerate.

Comment: “… it’s coating …” - I guess that’s a muffin pan with non-stick coating?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We're going to need more information about the muffin pan you're using: material, brand, ideally a photo.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Hey there, I found the previous question to be too wordy so I've rephrased it to something a bit more succinct. I don't currently have a muffin pan since I'm still doing some research on how hot the pan might go and buying one depending on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tins for pastéis de nata are typically made of [galvanized steel](https://pasgelpan.com/store/home/7168-formas-pasteis-f4.html) or [aluminum](https://loja.istofaz-se.pt/index.php/forma-pastel-de-nata-aluminio.html), without coating. In commercial bakeries it is also common to see [disposable tins](https://www.ideiapack-online.pt/Formas-de-aluminio-para-pasteis-de-nata) made with aluminum foil.

You can use a muffin tin made from the same materials: uncoated galvanized steel or aluminum

All recipes for that I've ever seen ask for a minimum temperature of 250°C (or as far as your oven can go, if it goes above that, which many ovens nowadays won't be able to go too far above it), so you can take 250 as a ballpark temperature for choosing your muffin tins

Use the broiler to finish them and get the charred spots after your pastéis are cooked (usually 25 minutes at 250 would do)

Comment: If you're finishing them under the broiler, you could probably take them out of the original pan and put them on a plain baking sheet - they'll have structure by then.

Comment: Wait, *galvanized* steel?  Are you sure?  That seems ... risky.  You sure it's not some other kind of steel?

Comment: I'm going to strongly recommend that the OP stick to *stainless* steel and not galvanized.  Galvanized steel can start emitting zinc at 250C, which would be toxic.

Comment: @FuzzyChef it's literally written there on the website - that shop is pretty popular

Comment: Juliana: ceramics with leaded glazes are also very popular throughout Latin America.  That doesn't make them non-toxic.  And even though the site says "galvanized" the photo looks like stainless.  So possibly a translation issue.